# Char data type holds \n while it's two bytes

Tags: c

I'm running into an issue trying to make some functions to make FileIO in C easier, where \n is stored as two bytes on the computer, but is held in a single char. This results in the file loaded being slightly shorter than the real size, giving some extra junk on the end. I'm using chars as bytes because it's the only data type that holds a single byte.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long getFileSize(char fileName[]) {
    FILE* f;
    long size;
    f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    return size;
}

char* readFile(char fileName[]) {
    FILE* f;
    char* data;
    long size;
    f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    size = getFileSize(fileName);
    data = malloc(size);
    fread(data, 1, size, f);
    fclose(f);
    return data;
}

char* writeFile(char fileName[], char* data, long length) {
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(fileName, "w");
    fwrite(data, 1, length, f);
    fclose(f);
    return data;
}

int main(void) {
    char* data = readFile("test.txt");
    long size = getFileSize("test.txt");
    int i;
    printf("%li\n", size);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%c", *(data + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    writeFile("test.txt", data, size);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think \n is involved

Comment: @neuhaus The amount of newlines in the original text document is directly correlated to the amount of extra characters printed out/written into the document. Looking at file sizes, newlines also appear to use 2 bytes instead of 1, changing the expected file size.

Comment: `fopen(fileName, "r");` --> `fopen(fileName, "rb");`

Comment: Main trouble is that code assume that `ftell(f);` and `fread(data, 1, size, f);` return the same value.  Code should have used the return value of `fread` for writing.  Tip: in the future check all the return  values of I/O functions and test if they worked - especially when having trouble with code and I/O

Comment: @chux that answered my question, thanks!

Comment: There is no more important advise anyone can give that to validate ALL input. That means checking the return at minimum, and if required checking that the value you receive from the user (or file) falls within the expected range. Make it a habit to check the `man page` for each function you are not 100% familiar with for the parameter and return types and values. And always compile with *warnings enabled*, that means at minimum with `-Wall -Wextra` for `gcc` or `/W3` for `cl.exe` (e.g. VS on windoze)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I do compile with warnings enabled, I had just forgot about there being a difference between opening files normally and in binary.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just noting the absence of actually validating `f` being open for reading after `f = fopen(fileName, "r");` E.g. `if (!f) { /* handle error */}`? Same holds following `f = fopen(fileName, "w");`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was me having used "w" and "r" instead of "wb" and "rb", as pointed out by @chux

> fopen(fileName, "r"); --> fopen(fileName, "rb");

Oops.